# How to update IOptions / configuration in ASP.NET Core integration tests?

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-configuration

I have an ASP.NET Core web application and writing integration test to run the server in-memory using `WebApplicationFactory` (ie. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests)

As usual, application services are configurable, in other words we inject using `IOptions<>` into various services. I'd like to test different configuration scenarios, which I'd define dynamically during test runtime.

For example:

```
public class EmailSenderOptions
{
    public string Sender { get; set; }
}

// Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.Configure<EmailSenderOptions>(config.GetSection("EmailSender"));

// Test
[TestFixture]
public class EmailSenderTests
{
     WebApplicationFactory<MyStartup> SUT = //omitted...

     [TestCase("noreply@mycompany.com")]
     [TestCase("easy-hookup@hackersite.com")]
     public void TestSender(string sender)
     {
         var client = SUT.CreateClient();
         SUT.Configuration.Set("EmailSender:Sender", sender); // <-- how?
         
         await client.GetAsync("/email");
     }
}
```

I'm aware that I could create test implementation for `IOptions`, but that would be much more difficult especially if `IOptionsMonitor` is being used. So I'm looking for a way just to overwrite the configuration *values* runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can obtain `IConfiguration` from services, since it has been registered as a singleton by host builder during application startup. We can also set values using the indexer. The "trick" is we need also to call reload (it is available through `IConfigurationRoot` interface) to populate changes

```
internal static void SetConfiguration(this WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> Sut, string key, string value)
{
    var config = Sut.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    if (config is IConfigurationRoot root)
    {
        root[key] = value;
        root.Reload();
    }
}

// Call like
SUT.SetConfiguration("EmailSender:Sender", "sender@mail.com");
```

Other alternative would be to create an own `IConfigurationSource` and supply values through a dictionary. This is much more coda and also requires to implement `IConfigurationProvider` and still need to call reload.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to use your typed `EmailSenderOptions` to set value in tests, you may consider [MutableOptions NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MutableOptions/) *(I am the author of that package)*.
It would look like that:

```
// Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.ConfigureMutable<EmailSenderOptions>(config.GetSection("EmailSender"));

// Test
// Instead of SUT.Configuration.Set("EmailSender:Sender", sender);
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMutator<EmailSenderOptions>>().Mutate(options => options with { Sender = sender });
```